# Android: Passing String ArraryList through intent. Value received null

Tags: java, android

I am passing a String array list through an intent  and when I get it from the bundle I get a null value. Do you know what the error is? Is it because I am using it inside the newMyFriendRequest method?

```
            final Bundle extras = new Bundle();

            extras.putString(EXTRA_PROFILENAME, profile.getFirstName());
            extras.putString(EXTRA_PROFILEID, profile.getId());

            final ArrayList<String> listids = new ArrayList<String>();
            final ArrayList<String> listnames = new ArrayList<String>();


            GraphRequestBatch batch = new GraphRequestBatch(
                    GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONArray jsonArray, GraphResponse response) {
                                    // Application code for users friends
                                    System.out.println("getFriendsData onCompleted : jsonArray " + jsonArray);
                                    System.out.println("getFriendsData onCompleted : response " + response);
                                    try {

                                        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                                        {
                                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                            listids.add(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                                            listnames.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                                            System.out.println("Iteration: " + i);
                                            System.out.println("Name: "+jsonObject.getString("name") );
                                            System.out.println("ID: "+jsonObject.getString("id") );

                                        }

                                        extras.putStringArrayList("names", listnames);
                                        extras.putStringArrayList("ids", listids);

                                        System.out.println("Names: " + listnames);
                                        System.out.println("IDs: " + listids);

                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            })

            );

            batch.addCallback(new GraphRequestBatch.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onBatchCompleted(GraphRequestBatch graphRequests) {
                    // Application code for when the batch finishes
                }
            });
            batch.executeAsync();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainLobby.class);

            intent.putExtras(extras);

            startActivity(intent);
```

In the activity OnCreate Method:

```
    intent = getIntent();

    Bundle extras =  intent.getExtras();
    //value is null not passing correctly
    listids = extras.getStringArrayList("ids");
    listnames = extras.getStringArrayList("names");

     System.out.println("MainLobby");
    System.out.println("Name: " + listnames);   
    System.out.println("User Logged In: " + user_name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put this code :

```
`Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainLobby.class);

 intent.putExtras(extras);

 startActivity(intent);`
```

right after your for loop inside `GraphRequestBatch` because according to the developer site,

> `executeAsync()` - Executes this batch asynchronously. This function will return immediately, and the batch will be processed on a separate thread. In order     to process results of a request, or determine whether a request succeeded or failed, a callback must be specified (see GraphRequest.setCallback(GraphRequest.Callback)).

Before the data is even present in the intent, next Activity is already started..

This should work but didn't tried this myself.